# How to populate a json object array from user's input?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have my code below. I've made an empty array, but I don't know how to connect them. Also I tried to get the value from my combo box, but it's giving me an error. The textbox tho takes the value from the user's input but not the combo box.

```js
function sample() {
  var jsObject = [];
  jsObject {
    "salutation": null,
    "fname": null
  };
  var sal = document.getElementById('salutation').value;
  var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  if (fname.value == "") {
    return false;
  }
  for (var key in sal) {
    sal = sal[key];
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="sam" onsubmit="return sample()" method="post">
    <select name="salutation">
    <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
    <option value="mrs">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="dr">Dr.</option>
   </select><br> Name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required placeholder="Enter name">
    <input type="submit" onclick="sample(); return false;" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have syntax errors and you should not use forms + post if you're not actually sending any data to a server. Also, you call sample both with the button click and with the onsubmit event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a select element that looks like this:

```
<select id="ddlViewBy">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

Running this code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Would make strUser be 2. If what you actually want is test2, then do this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Which would make strUser be test2

Comment: the original answer is here answered by @Paolo Bergantino[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript]